# How do I reverse a slice in go?

Tags: go, slice

How do I reverse an arbitrary slice (`[]interface{}`) in Go? I'd rather not have to write `Less` and `Swap` to use `sort.Reverse`. Is there a simple, builtin way to do this?

Comment: Note that `sort.Reverse` doesn't reverse the slice: instead it will sort the slice in descending order.

Comment: To clarify previous comment: `sort.Reverse()` does not sort the slice in reverse order. It will cause the `sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(...))` to sort the slice in reverse order. Unfortunately, `sort.Reverse()` requires a `sort.Interface()` which makes it quite verbose to use (whereas `sort.Sort()` does not) and returns a `sort.Interface`, and this interface does not have slice semantics (so you can't do `for _, x := range sort.Reverse()`).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use [slices.Reverse](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#Reverse) in Go 1.21 or later:

```
slices.Reverse(s)
```

---

Answers for Go version 1.20 and earlier:

The standard library does not have a built-in function for reversing a slice. Use a for loop to reverse a slice:

```
for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
```

Use type parameters to write a generic reverse function in Go 1.18 or later:

```
func reverse[S ~[]E, E any](s S)  {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
}
```

Use [reflect.Swapper](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Swapper) to write a function that works with arbitrary slice types in Go version 1.8 or later:

```
func reverse(s interface{}) {
    n := reflect.ValueOf(s).Len()
    swap := reflect.Swapper(s)
    for i, j := 0, n-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        swap(i, j)
    }
}
```

The functions in this answer reverse the slice inplace. If you do not want to modify the original slice, [copy the slice](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) before reversing the slice.

Comment: Beware of performance.
The answer below runs faster.
   
      BenchmarkA-8         011811777        100.40 ns/op
      BenchmarkB-8         29796914        044.17 ns/op

Comment: What does the `~` character do in the slice type definition of `func reverse[S ~[]E, E any](s S)`?

Comment: @Matze `~[]E` is use for custom slice type, such as `type mySlice []int`

Answer (score 10):

Here's another possible way to reverse generic slice (go 1.18)

```golang
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    nums := []int64{10, 5, 15, 20, 1, 100, -1}
    ReverseSlice(nums)
    fmt.Println(nums)

    strs := []string{"hello", "world"}
    ReverseSlice(strs)
    fmt.Println(strs)

    runes := []rune{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'}
    ReverseSlice(runes)
    for _, r := range runes {
        fmt.Print(string(r), " ")
    }
}

func ReverseSlice[T comparable](s []T) {
    sort.SliceStable(s, func(i, j int) bool {
        return i > j
    })
}
```

Running the program above should output:

```
[-1 100 1 20 15 5 10]
[world hello]
d l r o w o l l e h 
Program exited.
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uo9nd7pnS-o)</kbd>

Comment: This approach appears to rely on implementation details of [`sort.SliceStable`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#SliceStable). As such it might not work in all Go versions for all inputs. In general the expectation for the comparison function is that it is a function of the slice elements, not the positions. I see nothing in the documentation that would guarantee the behavior you're observing.

Comment: this will be O(n*Log(n)) at best. 
reverse only needs to be O(n)

Answer (score 8):

This will return a reversed slice without modifying the original slice.

Algorithm used from official wiki page: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#reversing

```
func reverse(s []interface{}) []interface{} {
    a := make([]interface{}, len(s))
    copy(a, s)

    for i := len(a)/2 - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        opp := len(a) - 1 - i
        a[i], a[opp] = a[opp], a[i]
    }

    return a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are my code example, you can run it in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NikNBoUgwQq)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "errors"
)

func ReverseSlice(data interface{}) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    if value.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic(errors.New("data must be a slice type"))
    }
    valueLen := value.Len()
    for i := 0; i <= int((valueLen-1)/2); i++ {
        reverseIndex := valueLen - 1 - i
        tmp := value.Index(reverseIndex).Interface()
        value.Index(reverseIndex).Set(value.Index(i))
        value.Index(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(tmp))
    }
}


func main() {
    names := []string{"bob", "mary", "sally", "michael"}
    ReverseSlice(names)
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

Comment: You panic on empty slice :-). You should check that `if valueLen == 0 { return }` before loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I'm using with **generics** (go 1.18+). You can use it to reverse any kind of slice or even a string (using the split/join trick). It doesn't change the original slice.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func Reverse[T any](original []T) (reversed []T) {
    reversed = make([]T, len(original))
    copy(reversed, original)

    for i := len(reversed)/2 - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        tmp := len(reversed) - 1 - i
        reversed[i], reversed[tmp] = reversed[tmp], reversed[i]
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    fmt.Println(a, Reverse(a))

    b := []uint{0, 1, 2}
    fmt.Println(b, Reverse(b))

    c := "abc"
    fmt.Println(c, strings.Join(Reverse(strings.Split(c, "")), ""))
}
```

[Better Go Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/37-MxfGC4Mp)

Answer (score 1):

```golang
func Reverse[T any](array []T) []T {
    length := len(array)
    result := make([]T, length)
    for i, elem := range array {
        result[length-1-i] = elem
    }
    return result
}

func ReverseInPlace[T any](array []T) []T {
    length := len(array)
    swap := reflect.Swapper(array)
    for i := 0; i < length/2; i++ {
        swap(i, length-1-i)
    }
    return array
}
```

Enhanced the accepted answer.

And tests:

```golang
func TestReverse(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Empty array", func(t *testing.T) {
        input := []int{}
        assert.Equal(t, []int{}, Reverse(input))
        assert.Equal(t, []int{}, input)
    })

    t.Run("Reverse integers", func(t *testing.T) {
        input := []int{1, 2, 3}
        assert.Equal(t, []int{3, 2, 1}, Reverse(input))
        assert.Equal(t, []int{1, 2, 3}, input)
    })

    t.Run("Reverse strings", func(t *testing.T) {
        input := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
        assert.Equal(t, []string{"c", "b", "a"}, Reverse(input))
        assert.Equal(t, []string{"a", "b", "c"}, input)
    })
}

func TestReverseInPlace(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Empty array", func(t *testing.T) {
        input := []int{}
        assert.Equal(t, []int{}, ReverseInPlace(input))
        assert.Equal(t, []int{}, input)
    })

    t.Run("Reverse integers", func(t *testing.T) {
        input := []int{1, 2, 3}
        assert.Equal(t, []int{3, 2, 1}, ReverseInPlace(input))
        assert.Equal(t, []int{3, 2, 1}, input)
    })

    t.Run("Reverse strings", func(t *testing.T) {
        input := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
        assert.Equal(t, []string{"c", "b", "a"}, ReverseInPlace(input))
        assert.Equal(t, []string{"c", "b", "a"}, input)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This generic slice reversal function should do it for you:

```
func ReverseSlice[T comparable](s []T) []T {
  var r []T
  for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
    r = append(r, s[i])
  }
  return r
}
```