# Golang reverse a arbitrary slice

Tags: go

```
var Reverse = func(slice interface{}) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    // if s is a pointer of slice
    if s.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        s = s.Elem()
    }
    i := 0
    j := s.Len() - 1
    for i < j {
        x, y := s.Index(i).Interface(), 
           s.Index(j).Interface()
        s.Index(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(y))
        s.Index(j).Set(reflect.ValueOf(x))
        i++
        j--
    }
}
```

I found this way works.But it is not elegant....
I know there is a method "Swapper" in reflect package. But I don't know how to make it work if the argument of above function is a pointer of slice.

Really appreciate.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#reversing

Comment: I know the a,b=b,a trick. But that is for specific type of slice....my function here is a arbitrary type of slice, so I need to use the reflect package...I think things are different....maybe I am wrong...thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse a slice in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058278/how-do-i-reverse-a-slice-in-go)

Comment: oh,thanks.My mistake. I should add comment in your answer.Actually I want to know the situation if the argument is pointer of slice (swapper won't work).And the answer in my question helped me. thank you

Comment: Sorry, It is just a exercise I found in internet.Thanks for your further guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse a slice in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058278/how-do-i-reverse-a-slice-in-go)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. To use `reflect.Swapper`, just pass `s.Interface()` into it:

```
var Reverse = func(slice interface{}) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    // if s is a pointer of slice
    if s.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        s = s.Elem()
    }
    swp := reflect.Swapper(s.Interface())
    for i,j :=0,s.Len() - 1; i<j; i,j = i+1,j-1 {
        swp(i,j)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DSq_iZRZX4b