# how to reverse array | slice in golang without using for statement

Tags: go

I'm looking for a way to reverse `[][]string|int` in Golang without using any `for` statement.
I couldn't find any solution. I found this post [How do I reverse a slice in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28058278/5728991), but every solution is used `for` statement. I know the best way to handle this problem is using `for`, but I'm looking for other solutions without having for

```
 list := [][]int{
            {2,3,4}, 
            {6,8,1},
        }
```

the result is like this: `[[2 3 4] [6 8 1]].`

but I need something like this: `[[6 8 1] [2 3 4]].`

What should I do without using the `for` statement? Is there any idea?

Comment: `What should I do without using the for statement? Is there any idea?`  bet you can write it using goto statements.

Comment: See [How do I reverse a slice in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28058278/5728991) if you are not actually constrained by the strange requirement of not using a for  loop.

Comment: This is a question from a company, they said you should solve this problem without using any `for` statement. I know this not a good question, but I was wondering is there any other way to solve this part, so I wrote here, and I got 3 negative votes :D by the way, I guess the best way to handle something like this is using the `Recursion` function, @mh-cbon and @Cerise thanks for the link, I saw it before and I couldn't find the answer that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do without using the for statement? Is there any idea?

recursive calls

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    list := [][]int{
        {2, 3, 4},
        {6, 8, 1},
    }
    reverse(list)
    fmt.Println(list)
}

func reverse(d [][]int) {
    j := len(d) - 1
    i := 0
    var h func()
    h = func() {
        if i<j {
            d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i]
            i, j = i+1, j-1
            h()
        }
    }
    h()
}
```

goto statements

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    list := [][]int{
        {2, 3, 4},
        {6, 8, 1},
    }
    reverse(list)
    fmt.Println(list)
}

func reverse(d [][]int) {
    j := len(d) - 1
    i := 0
START:
    if i < j {
        d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i]
        i, j = i+1, j-1
        goto START
    }

}
```

if you read that far, read about a regular solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058324/4466350

Answer (score 1):

Using `for` loop here - is the simplest solution.

**PS**: You can try to use hardcoded solution like this one:

```
list2 := [][]int{list[1], list[0]}
```

but it's rather hack than solution,

so better to use nice and concise programmatic solution base on `for` loop.

Comment: thank you @cn007b for sure using `for` is the best way to handle something like this but, it's not my fault, as I said this is a question from a company, they said you should solve this problem without using any for statement, so, for now, the best answer for me is using `goto` or using something like `Recursion` function, I know its not good I idea but for now it's fine :)

Comment: Just curious, why using for loop is not allowed? 

Comment: I don't know, I asked by email, but I don't get any response. I'm still waiting.